# Ksh nested substitution

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, aix, substitution

I have the following configuration file:

```
export PROFILE_ACTIVE=0 

export PROFILE_SCSADP01[0]="0 84"
export PROFILE_SCSADP04[0]="85 170"
export PROFILE_SCSADP05[0]="171 255"

export PROFILE_SCSADP01[1]="-1 -1"
export PROFILE_SCSADP04[1]="85 170|0 42"
export PROFILE_SCSADP05[1]="171 255|43 84"
```

I would like to access these variable using substitution in a ksh script:

I can easily access each variable using this syntax, which is working:

result=${**PROFILE_SCSADP01**[${PROFILE_ACTIVE}]}

However I need the bold part to be variable, not fixed.

I have tired this syntax:

```
Temp="PROFILE_SCSADP01"
result=${$Temp[${PROFILE_ACTIVE}]}
```

However I always get a bad substituion error.
I have tried to look for workaround, but cannot find any working,

Comment: Alternatively, you can make the digits inside the [ and ] the only variable. For example, `PROFILE_SCSADP01[0]` could become `PROFILE_SCSADP[10]`, and `PROFILE_SCSADP01[1]` could become  `PROFILE_SCSADP[11]`. That way, you're removing the need to work with variables both inside the [ and ] and as part of the variable name itself. You can use 101, or 1001, or whatever is needed.

Comment: Or make a function that will grep and cut a configfile with lines like `SET1_PROFILE_SCSADP01="0 84"` (SET1/SET2 active).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ksh` has the `typeset -n` command for this ([see here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection)), which I think would be the preferred solution:

```
typeset -n tmp="PROFILE_SCSADP01"
result=${tmp[${PROFILE_ACTIVE}]}
```

You could also use`eval` ([be careful](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)) for this:

```
tmp="PROFILE_SCSADP01"
result=$(eval echo \${$tmp[${PROFILE_ACTIVE}]})
```

`eval` parses the command once before it is run, so after the `eval` completes, the resulting command looks like this:

```
result=$(echo ${PROFILE_SCSADP01[0]})
```